# Getting error during making a SSIS services

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server-2008, ssis

during making a SSIS i m getting error.
my senario is i have a Excel sheet which is a source and have a table name department as a destination source in SQL SeRVer,

I have done my work in Control flow and work flow, but in SQL SERVER destination i m getting error pls have a look.

> ### TITLE: Package Validation Error
>
> Package Validation Error
>
> ------------------------------ ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> Error at Data Flow Task [SQL Server
>   Destination [222]]: Column
>   "DepartmentID" cannot convert between
>   unicode and non-unicode string data
>   types.
>
> Error at Data Flow Task [SQL Server
>   Destination [222]]: Column
>   "DepartmentName" cannot convert
>   between unicode and non-unicode string
>   data types.
>
> Error at Data Flow Task
>   [SSIS.Pipeline]: "component "SQL
>   Server Destination" (222)" failed
>   validation and returned validation
>   status "VS_ISBROKEN".
>
> Error at Data Flow Task
>   [SSIS.Pipeline]: One or more component
>   failed validation.
>
> Error at Data Flow Task: There were
>   errors during task validation.
>
> (Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.VsIntegration)

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to do implicit conversions (unicode to non-unicode string) which SSIS will not do for you.

You will have to use the Data Conversion component or the Derived Column component to do explicit conversions before sending the data to the destination.